# UnauthorizedAccessException : Getting in Vista

Tags: .net, exception, windows-vista

I made a application and its working fine in XP, but getting UnauthorizedAccessException in vista. Basically I am creating a folder through code and writing a XML file in it.

Is there a way I can make the application run as administrator through code or something.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself, "Does my app really need to write to a protected part of the hard disk?"  Most often I've found that people just assume they can write wherever they want.  The solution is not to give the app admin privs, but to write the file to the users profile which is probably where it belongs.

Comment: yes I am using this in FTP Client application, in which I need to make folder and files.

Answer (score 1):

To make an application perform a UAC prompt you need to add a suitable [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) to your application. [VS2008](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/08/video-build-uac-aware-apps-with-vs2008.html) is aware of manifest files and provides support for them. Of course really putting this file in a user's directory would be better, but sometimes you can't avoid creating things where you need UAC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your app as requiring admin privileges in the application manifest. Here's an article from MSDN Magazine that explains the process:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx#S8